# Pygame : create a subsurface that cannot modify parent image, but can be modified by parent

Tags: python, pygame, pygame-surface

I'm trying to create a subsurface of another surface but only linked by the parent -> child side.

It should have the property of a subsurface if we want  to modify the parent surface : the child should also be  modified.
However it should have the property of a copy if we want to modify the child surface : the parent should **not** be modified.

For example :

```
#1 step : all the "subsurfaces" are created from "myimage"
parent = ('myimage.png')
child = parent.subsurface((32,96,32,32))
prop = parent.subsurface((0,0,32,32))
child.blit(prop_to_blit,(0,0))

#2 step : the parent image is modified
parent.blit('otherimage.png')
```

At the end of the 1st step the child surface should look like child+prop but the parent should stay intact.

At the end of the 2nd step, the parent being modified, all the subsurfaces should be modified too.

For my program to work, I need to blit another image onto the parent image (thus having a "subsurface" function with these properties).
I've tried alternatives to this solution, all needed to directly modify the parent image with variable assignment then reloading the file. But it cannot work because of a cyclic module call

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A subsurface shares the pixels with the source surface. Therefore it is not possible, that the surface shares the pixels in one direction but not in the other direction. However you can [`copy()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.copy) a *Surface* whenever you  want.
So you have to make a decision. Either you want to share with pixels or you want to copy the pixels. `copy` the 2st subsurface and `blit` the 2nd subsurface on it:

```py
child = parent.subsurface((32,96,32,32)).copy()
prop = parent.subsurface((0,0,32,32))
child.blit(prop_to_blit,(0,0))
```

Comment: If I blit on the parent surface then, is there a way to get this blit on the copy too ?

Comment: No there is no way. A Surface is just a bunch of  pixels arranged in a grid. If you `blit` a surface onto another surface (e.g. `child.blit(prop_to_blit,(0,0))`), the color information stored in the pixels is blended and the original color is overwritten. Things are much simpler than you assume it to be.